# CCNET - build task required? Multiple repositories, one CCNET source section per project

Tags: asp.net, git, continuous-integration, sitecore, ccnet-config

CCNET questions - Here's the scenario:

- I've got 10 developers doing local development to a Sitecore installation w/GIT as version control. When done with their feature/fix they push to an integration repository.
- I've got CCNET setup for the Sitecore project that points to the remote Integration rep and the local live qa code base. CCNET finds the commits that my developers have made to integration repository and then updates the qa code base repository.
- I also have a couple other .Net class lib projects that are managed by CCNET, compiled with their output pointed to the Sitecore bin dir.
- The Sitecore installation is merely a result of a build with no compilable aspects. Its a web product with it's own API as well as the ability to integrate custom dll that we create to customize the product.

Questions:

1. Is CCNET build task required as a condition to execute other activities such as nUnit or robocopy? (the reason I ask this is because a "build" is natively used to compile an app and generate output, whereas, the only reason why we'd want to build is to make sure all dependencies are there and we can jump to unit testing...).
2. If my developers are NOT pointing to a centralized rep like integration, how would CCNET know where all of their remote GIT repositories are when the config doc only allows one GIT source control section per project?
3. Per project when I configure the GIT vc specs it asks for the branch that needs to be statically saved to the doc. Does CCNET have the ability to accept different branches dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's no need to have an "actual build" in your project - it could consist of any type of tasks inside the `tasks` element. I have a couple of projects which only copy the files from the repository to an FTP server after deleting some files which shouldn't be published.
2. I have no experience with GIT but you have a possibility to define multiple source control blocks of any type if you use the [multi source control block](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Multi+Source+Control+Block).
3. You could use [dynamic parameters](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Dynamic+Parameters) which allow the user to set their values when triggering the build.